# Issues with checkboxes checking other check boxes on App

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am trying to make a checkbox in android studio/java that if checked will result in a subset of other checkboxes checkable and checked.

The developer site says:
abstract void   setChecked(boolean checked)
Change the checked state of the view

But this hasn't worked for me.

Current code:

Java:

```
package crc.cybereye;

public class CreateNew extends Activity {
    LinearLayout background;
    Button btnBack;
    CheckBox checkbox_structural_info;
    CheckBox checkbox_years_of;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        checkbox_years_of = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_years_of);
        checkbox_floors_above = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_floors_above);
        checkbox_structural_info = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_structural_info);
       // setUpIntroCheckBoxes(); // Add change listeners to check boxes


        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewFormActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

More Java:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_structural_info:
            if (checked){
                checkbox_years_of checked.setChecked(true) //ERROR HERE
            }
            break;
        case R.id.checkbox_years_of:
            if (checked){

            }
            break;
```

XML:

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/structural_info"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_structural_info"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
</TableRow>
  <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/years_of"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            />
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_years_of"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
   <TableRow>
```

There is an error saying that it cannot resolve method setChecked(boolean).

My code currently is just trying to get the structural_info checkbox to check the years_of checkbox if it is checked, but I also want to make years_or only checkable if structural_info is checked, I haven't got there yet because I was still stuck on this issue.
Thanks so much for any help in advance.

Comment: shouldn't checkbox_years_of checked.setChecked(true) be checkbox_years_of.setChecked(true) ? (there you're calling setChecked to checked wich is a boolean variable)

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks (still getting the hang of Java)

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can check it as the answer? Or is there some way to close this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by the creator of the post, i'm adding the comment as an answer:

You're calling setChecked to checked wich is a boolean variable.
You shoud write:

```
checkbox_years_of.setChecked(true)
```

Instead of

```
checkbox_years_of checked.setChecked(true)
```